# Existe alguma forma de tratar todas as Exceptions do software?

Tags: .net, vb.net, exceção

Estou criando uma *DLL* para uso em diversos projetos meus. Criei um método que captura a Source, a Message e outras variáveis que defini, monta um e-mail e envia para mim mesmo. (uma especie de log de erros por e-mail).

Existe alguma forma de referenciar esse método uma vez só no código e ele capturar todas as vezes que uma `Exception` for lançada mesmo sem `Try... Catch`?

Comment: Esqueci de comentar que o objetivo final não é tratar a Exception em si, quero apenas que ela seja enviada para meu email. Objetivo final é saber os bugs que acontecem nela após eu ter lançado sua primeira versão.

Comment: Você decide o que fazer quando uma exceção não tratada é detectada, ambas as respostas citam isso.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Você pode adicionar um  *event handler* para evento [`AppDomain.UnhandledException`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.unhandledexception.aspx), esse evento será acionado quando uma exceção não é detectada/tratada.

> Ele permite que o aplicativo registre informações sobre a exceção
>   antes do manipulador padrão do sistema relatar a exceção para o
>   usuário e encerrar o aplicativo. Se informações suficientes sobre o
>   estado da aplicação está disponível, outras medidas podem ser tomadas
>   - como salvar os dados do programa para a recuperação posterior.
>
> Aconselha-se precaução, porque os dados do programa podem ser
>   corrompidos quando exceções não são tratadas.

Exemplo retirado [**daqui**](http://tech.pro/tutorial/668/csharp-tutorial-dealing-with-unhandled-exceptions) em C#.

Adicione uma linha para o método principal (por padrão no arquivo *Program.cs* em um novo aplicativo do Windows):

```
namespace MyApp
{
  static class Program
  {
    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
      AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException +=  new UnhandledExceptionEventHandler(CurrentDomain_UnhandledException);
      Application.EnableVisualStyles();
      Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
      Application.Run(new Form1());
    }
  }
}
```

Na linha `AppDomain.CurrentDomain...` está referenciando uma função que ainda não existe, portanto, criaremos ela:

```
static void CurrentDomain_UnhandledException (object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
{
  try
  {
    Exception ex = (Exception)e.ExceptionObject;    
    MessageBox.Show("Erro! Entre em contato com os desenvolvedores com a seguinte" 
          + " informação:\n\n" + ex.Message + ex.StackTrace, 
          "Fatal Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Stop);
  }
  finally
  {
    Application.Exit();
  }
}
```

Agora suas exceções não tratadas estão sendo mostrados em um diálogo agradável, você pode fazer outras coisas por aqui - como registrar a exceção, ou tentar suavizar o golpe do acidente, você não pode no entanto, manter o programa rodando após um *crash*, não há uma maneira de pegar a exceção a esta altura e deixar o programa funcionando.

Em VB.NET deve ficar semelhante a isto:

```vb
Module MyApp   
   Sub Main()
      Dim currentDomain As AppDomain = AppDomain.CurrentDomain
      AddHandler currentDomain.UnhandledException, AddressOf MyHandler

      Throw New Exception("Foo")
   End Sub 

   Sub MyHandler(sender As Object, args As UnhandledExceptionEventArgs)
      Dim e As Exception = DirectCast(args.ExceptionObject, Exception)

      Console.WriteLine("Erro! Entre em contato com os desenvolvedores com a seguinte : " + e.Message)
      ' Fazer alguma coisa aqui com a exceção não tratada.
   End Sub     
End MyApp
```

Comment: Eu cai no mesmo erro, a pergunta é sobre vb.net.

Answer (score 3):

Sim, existe. Antes tem algumas coisas que quero lhe dizer.

Salvo alguma exceção (com o perdão do trocadilho) muito bem justificada só existe um local onde você deve capturar a `Exception`. É próximo do encerramento da aplicação. Muitas vezes no `Main()` ou algum método chamado por ele. É ali que você deve capturar todas as exceções lançadas e que não foram capturadas antes. É ali onde deve fazer o que você indicou. E quase sempre a aplicação deve quebrar mesmo, pode até ser de uma forma "bonitinha" mas é o melhor a fazer quando o problema não pode ser consertado. E erros de programação não podem ser consertados em tempo de execução. O máximo que você pode fazer fazer para não deixar quebrar é começar de novo com um estado zerado. A aplicação não quebraria mas começaria tudo de novo como se fosse a primeira execução. Por isto deve estar no `Main()` ou bem próximo dele.

Mas se você realmente quer capturar algo que nem assim foi capturado existe uma forma:

```
'isto possivelmente vai no Main
Dim currentDomain = AppDomain.CurrentDomain
currentDomain.UnhandledException += new unhandledExceptionEventHandler(MyHandler)

Shared Sub MyHandler(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs args) {
   Dim e =  DirectCast(args.ExceptionObject, Exception)
   Console.WriteLine("Erro: {0}", e.Message)
   'aqui você pode fazer o que quiser
End Sub
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/VB.NET/Handler.vb).

[Documentação](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.appdomain.unhandledexception?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=netcore-3.1).

Eu aconselho evitar este método, isto talvez não faça o que você espera.